# If $\sqrt[n]{x}$ is rational, then so is $x$.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, proof-writing

I am trying to show that if $x$ is irrational, then so is $\sqrt[n]{x}$ via contrapositive; that is, I want to assume that if $\sqrt[n]{x}$ is rational, then so is $x$ and this is how I proceeded with my attempt:

if $\sqrt[n]{x}$ is rational, then we write $\sqrt[n]{x}=\frac{u}{v}$ with $u\in\mathbb{Z^{+}}$ and $v\in\mathbb{Z}$ and $\gcd(u,v)=1$. We then have $x=\frac{u^{n}}{v^{n}}$ which implies that $u^{n}=xv^{n}$.

From this point, how can I continue, or should I abandon this method?

Comment: You method is correct. Notice that $u^n \in \mathbb Z^+$ and $v^n \in \mathbb Z$.

Comment: However, this needs proof, how can I show what you stated? should I prove that $\gcd(u^{n},v^{n})=1$? if so then how? and thank you sir.

Comment: It doesn't actually matter that $\gcd(u,v)=1$ and it doesn't matter that $\gcd(u^n,v^n)=1$.  So long as something can be written as the ratio of two integers, *regardless* whether it was in simplest form or not, that is enough to say it is rational.  It can sometimes be helpful to insist on simplest form for a fraction to help our argument (*e.g. for contradiction by noting that such a simplest form cannot exist as there is always simpler possible*) but it is not needed here.

Comment: The $\gcd$ plays no role in determining whether a number is rational. To prove $u^n$ is a positive integer just note that a product of positive integers is always a positive integer.

Comment: thank you very much for your comments, never the less, I must show that $u^{n}$ and $v^{n}$ are both integers using axioms of $Z$.

Comment: Because an integer times an integer is always another integer you have that $u$ an integer implies that $u\times u$ an integer.  $u$ and $u^k$ an integer implies that $u^{k+1}=u^k\times u$ an integer.  Together by induction you have $u$ an integer implies $u^n$ an integer for all natural $n\geq 1$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to show that if $x$ is irrational, then so is $x^{\frac{1}{n}}$. Well suppose $x$ is irrational and $x^{\frac{1}{n}}$ is rational.

Let $$x^{\frac{1}{n}}=\frac{u}{v}$$

Where $u$ and $v$ are coprime integers. Then, $$x=\frac{u^n}{v^n}$$

So $x$ is rational, which contradicts our claim. Thus $x^{\frac{1}{n}}$ is irrational.

Comment: by your last statement did you mean $x$ instead of $n$ being rational?

Comment: yes, my bad, sorry. edited

Answer (score 2):

Supposed that $n \in \mathbb{N}$, then you've already finished the proof: check that you reached $x = \frac{u^n}{v^n}$, which is the ratio of two integers, hence $x$ is rational.